# Creating Input Text using Css and HTML

Tags: html, css

I Need to have a div tag with two rows of text boxes.

The first row has 3 input text boxes with width and height calculated based on percentage.

Likewise in second row i need 2 input text boxes. As i have two input boxes, the area should be broken into 2 blocks of 50% each.

I am new to CSS and HTML.

I have tried a bit of code. but, didn't work!

```
#div1
{
    position: absolute;
}
#div1 text
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin:33%
}
#div2
{
    position: relative;
}
#div2 text
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin:50%
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <input type="text" name="txtbox1" class="clstxtbox1"/>
        <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox1" />
        <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox1" />
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <input type="text" name="txtbox1" class="clstxtbox2" />
        <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox2" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me

Comment: there are 3 answers and you did not accept one.do you accept one answer or do you add an image  in your mind ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css3 [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-holder">
  <input type="text" name="txtbox1" class="clstxtbox1"/>
  ...
  ...
  <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox1" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.input-holder {
  display: flex;
}

.input-holder input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```css
.input-holder {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.input-holder input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-holder">
  <input type="text" name="txtbox1" class="clstxtbox1"/>
  <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox1" />
  <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox1" />
</div>
<div class="input-holder">
  <input type="text" name="txtbox1" class="clstxtbox2" />
  <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox2" />
</div>
```

Here is another variant:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-holder">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="txtbox1" class="clstxtbox1"/>
  </div>
  ...
  ...
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.input-holder {
  display: flex;
}

.input-holder div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.input-holder div input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.input-holder {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.input-holder div {
  padding: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.input-holder div input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-holder">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="txtbox1" class="clstxtbox1"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox1" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox1" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-holder">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="txtbox1" class="clstxtbox2" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you tell me , how to add this hidden snippet

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271762/add-a-run-option-next-to-show-for-hidden-snippets

Comment: In first line of snippet `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true console: true babel: false -->` Change `hide: true` as `false`.

Comment: @JishnuVS Have you got it?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman you have got it man but iwant the 2 row textbox to occupy the width of first .

Comment: The Area occupied by the button should not diminish the 2 input in 2nd row should occupy 50% each

Comment: @SundarStalin sorry,  I didn't get your requirement exactly. Can you show me a fiddle or an image of what you want?

Comment: First row :100 % 3 input each input occupies 33 % of area

Comment: second row also 100 % as it has only 2 input it shpuld occupy 50% of area    .suppose assume if i have 4 input text in 3rd row it should occupy 25% of are

Comment: @SundarStalin In my snippet this is what is exactly happening. Where is the problem... If you will add another row having 4 inputs, they will be divided 25% space automatically...

Comment: Actually in the codesnippt its working good but when i render in chrome browser its not properly intended

Comment: @SundarStalin may be some other styles are overriding it. Can you create a fiddle of your complete code, I'll try to find problem?

Comment: In your fiddle itslef see the 3row is not occupying 25 % correctly i Need all the div elements input text in each row as same srat and end point

Comment: @SundarStalin In my chrome its all working fine. I'm not sure what is causing it to not work properly in your side.

Comment: I will accept your answer as i have got some partial o/p but i am unaware of the chrome behavior

Comment: @SundarStalin Which version of chrome are you using? And check in some other browser to check that it is working fine or not.

Comment: 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)

Comment: @SundarStalin same is mine.. Please inspect element and check that which other properties are applying in your styles. Hopefully you will find some clue.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman as you said some thing was overriding the max width i corrected it by  <style type="text/css">
        input, select, textarea {
            max-width: 100%;
        }

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use table  tags inside your div tags.

Your answer can look somewhat like below,

```html
<body>
  <div id="div1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="txtbox1" class="clstxtbox1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox1" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="txtbox1" class="clstxtbox2" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox2" />
        </td>
        <tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Later you can adjust the length and width of the td tags according to your wish.
Hope this helps.

Comment: i dont want to display in table

Answer (score 0):

```css
.second_row{
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtbox1" class="clstxtbox1"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox2"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtbox3" class="clstxtbox3"/>
</div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="row second_row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtbox1" class="clstxtbox1"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtbox2" class="clstxtbox2"/>
</div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi can i know how to do in css

Comment: you can do using flexbox as @MuhammadUsman has given. if you don't want to use much CSS the you can use bootstrap CSS Library.

Comment: Ok I am not exposed to bootstrap now my requirement was to do with css if you asked an requirement for muhammed if you can resolve it well and good